# HTML and CSS Background issues

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a site from scratch, to match a custom look and feel I want; however, I am coming up with some issues related to just starting it out.  I am wanting to fill a div element with an image; however, that image is being cut off (I want it to display the whole image with no cropping).  Also, I want this to be responsive; so I don't want to use px.  When I use percentages though nothing shows.  How do I alleviate these two issues I am having?

This is the JSFiddle that I have it working on:  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9h1n6nz2/13/)

I understand that making it responsive requires percentages or ems; how would I make this responsive?  When I change both width and heighth to 100% my image disappears.

Also, why is the width only responsive to a certain point when it is at 100% and height is at 800px?

Thank you

HTML

```
<body>

    <div id="Banner">
        <div id="Menu">

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#Banner
{
    width: 900px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url("../header.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

CSS

```
/* Resets (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ | v2.0 | 20110126 | License: none (public domain)) */

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block;}body{line-height:1;}ol,ul{list-style:none;}blockquote,q{quotes:none;}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none}

/* Box Model */

*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Container */

body {
    /* min-width: (containers) */
    min-width: 1200px;
}

.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    /* width: (containers) */
    width: 1200px;
}
```

Comment: only post the code that's absolutely necessary for us to understand your situation please

Comment: Jason, you did a wrong edit. A big part of the code you deleted was needed to answer the second part of your question (responsiveness). If anything, just add it again and remove the styling you had

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another 100% on there:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

And see how those work for you.

### [Edited JS Fiddle that shows what you want to achieve.](http://jsfiddle.net/9h1n6nz2/18/)

### [More on background size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: actually, I think he needs `background-size:contain;` (with `cover` some clipping may occur, with `contain` the image is always fully visible, pillow bars will be created if the aspect ratio doesn't match)

Comment: the answer by Remy is correct, although partial (there's another part to the question). the `contain` answer is incorrect, I've made a fiddle to show you what happens at http://jsfiddle.net/9h1n6nz2/ , try changing to cover and see how it works

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this.  My image is still cropped/cut off, either of the two ways mentioned

Comment: try copying my Fiddle code, changing contain to cover

Comment: I modified your Fiddle code to just input the picture from the current website I'm changing.  http://jsfiddle.net/9h1n6nz2/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9h1n6nz2/18/

Works as you want. Bordered the box just to make sure.